# Body Becomes Empty When Received By Server

Tags: fetch

Hello My Fetch Request To My Server Is Going But The Body Returns {}
My Server Code

```
app.post('/log', (req, res) => {

console.log(req.body)
console.log(req)
});
```

My Client Code

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('key', 'value');
  fetch(`/log`, {
    mode: "cors",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': "application/json"
    },
    body: formData,
     }
    )
```

Comment: What server are you using?  Can you post any more information?  Can you paste the output?  Can you paste the client data before its sent to show the body is not indeed empty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put `app.use(express.json())` **before** your route handler.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/log', (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.body)
});
```

In client please stringify the object

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key', 'value');

fetch(`/log`, {
  mode: 'cors',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(formData)
});
```

Comment: Nope Not Working
Error :-
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (/home/runner/home-invite-rewards/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:89:19)
    at /home/runner/home-invite-rewards/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/home/runner/home-invite-rewards/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/home/runner/home-invite-rewards/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/home/runner/home-invite-rewards/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)

Comment: Please use `body : JSON.stringify(formData)` in client